# Is there an AngularJS equivalent to $(document).ajaxSuccess()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

In AngularJS, I wish to create a catch-all-be-all ajax loader that does not need to be weaved into each controller in order to work.  Traditionally, in jQuery I can do something like this:

```
(function globalAjaxLoader($){
 "use strict";
    var ajaxBoundElements = [$posts, $navigationLinks];
    ajaxBoundElements.forEach(function($elm){
       $elm.on('click', function(){
          $loader.show();
       });
    $(document).ajaxSuccess(function (event, XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions){
      $loader.hide();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

However, in AngularJS I am not seeing a global way of detecting ajaxCompletion (that is without going through the promise returned for each ajax call made through Angular individually)?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll want to look into httpInterceptors -- you're probably looking to show and hide your loader in the `request` and `response` or `responseError` sections of the interceptor

Comment: @Tom Yes, I began reading up on this however I was never able to find the method or proper technique for the loader to function properly. I also see a bunch or incomplete/unanswered ajax loader questions on SO but most lead no where in regards to globally applying this functionality.

Comment: So since the DOM is being manipulated by showing/hiding the loader, is there anyway to do the show hide part in a directive as the NG docs suggest? Aside from that what you say is very straight forward (thank you)

Comment: Who dv's on a question like this? I did my research, my code is short and sweet (and correct)... there should be mandatory explanation for downvoting questions, and if that user dv's for no reason they should get banned :/ but thats just what I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://jsbin.com/vubevogaju/edit?html,js,output) I've put together a jsBin showing how to do this with an http interceptor.

I've used `$rootScope.loadingCount` so you can actually `ng-show` and `ng-hide` your based on that.  Here is an example of the markup (you'd obviously use something a bit different:

```
<h1 ng-show="loadingCount > 0">Loading...</h1>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .config(httpInterceptorConfig)
  .factory('loadingDialogInterceptor', loadingDialogInterceptor);

// create your interceptor
loadingDialogInterceptor.$inject = ['$q', '$rootScope'];
function loadingDialogInterceptor($q, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.loadingCount = 0;

  function showLoading() {
    $rootScope.loadingCount++;
  }

  function hideLoading() {
    if ($rootScope.loadingCount > 0) {
      $rootScope.loadingCount--;
    }
  }

  return {
    request: function (config) {
      showLoading();
      return config || $q.when(config);
    },
    response: function(response) {
      hideLoading();

      return response || $q.when(response);
    },
    responseError: function(response) {
      hideLoading();

      return $q.reject(response);
    }
  };
}

// actually register your interceptor
httpInterceptorConfig.$inject = ['$httpProvider'];
function httpInterceptorConfig($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('loadingDialogInterceptor');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same with interceptors.

```
myModule
.factory('httpResponseInterceptor', [
    '$q',
    function ($q) {
        return {
            request: function (request) {
                $loader.show();
                return request;
            },
            requestError: function () {
                $loader.hide();
            },
            response: function (response) {
                $loader.hide();
                return response || $q.when(response);
            },
            responseError: function (rejection) {
                $loader.hide();
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        }
    }
])
.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpResponseInterceptor');

    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.push(function (data) {
        $loader.show();
        return data;
    });
})
```